# Which Java based web framework has better protection against XSRF?

Tags: java, gwt, wicket, vaadin

I was wondering to know which Java web framework has a better built-in protection against XSRF (Cross Site Request Forgery) attacks.

I know that GWT provides this protection, well if configured as described [here](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideSecurityRpcXsrf.html), but don't know if others have a better built-in protection. I'm particularly intersted in Vaadin and Wicket, but my lists of options is open.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any established, well-known framework (like the ones you describe), **when configured correctly** should provide you with ample security. Also, any framework that you use will *have* to do some manual configuration to get it working properly in your specific environment. *"Out-of-the-box"* setups typically only provice you with the most basic, generic security protection.

Personally, I would suggest going the GWT route and following their dev guide. But that's just because I like GWT, and we have gone down that route. You can find a ton of usefull information at [OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/).

You should also look at integrating [Spring](http://www.springsource.com/) with your GWT application for very nice security.

Just a note about Vaadin. Make sure it fits your development need. It is a great framework that makes a lot of things really easy, but just remeber that **every** UI interaction you do makes a server-side request. So if you are in a low-latency environment, go ahead, but be carefull of you have high latencies and you want to provide a very quick UI response time. But again, I don't want to undermine Vaadin, it is really a great framework.

Comment: The same is true to a certain extent for Wicket: every piece of validation or scripting will make a round-trip to the server and back. Unless of course you roll your own, which comes with its own pitfalls.